# Date to Correct Format (Ex. 01-MAR-2017 00:00:00)

Tags: vba, excel

Every time I've tried to change my date to a specific format, excel automatically autoformats to "3/1/2017 0:00" instead of 01-MAR-2017 00:00:00.

My code is the following:

```
objMasterDefectLog.Sheets(1).Range(strFrozenCustReqDateLoc).Offset(iCounter, 0).Value = Format(tempString, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Even if I convert tempString into a date, it still does not format correctly. I would rather not parse everything out if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want the cell to contain the date/time, or text that presents the date/time? If the former, use @Peh's example. If the latter, you could force it with the old apostrophe trick:

```
...Offset(iCounter, 0).Value = "'" & Ucase(Format(tempString, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Where is the benefit of having a date formatted as text instead of using a date? I only see disadvantages.

Comment: Totally agree with you. But we can't see the rest of the code. Who knows what that cell is used for later! Just presenting an alternative in case it's needed.

Comment: OK, just thought you had something specific in mind.

Comment: Sorry, this could be stored as string, but I don't want the " ' " to be included in the text. Likewise the below code works, but I need MAR to be uppercase. UCase doesn't work well with dates.

Comment: It is included in the text, but you won't ever see it unless you look at the formula input box. Even if you query it with `.Text` or `.Value` you won't get the `'` returned. It won't be output if you save as text etc. - Also, edited answer to UCASE it.

Comment: @Peh, I think Nolan has managed to find a benefit that neither of us foresaw. Upper-casing. I can't think how you'd do this in just formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You need also to define the format of the cell after you set the value. Setting a `.Value` only sets a value of a cell but not the format. So you additionally need to format the cell:

```
objMasterDefectLog.Sheets(1).Range(strFrozenCustReqDateLoc).Offset(iCounter, 0).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

See also: [Range.NumberFormat Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx)

Comment: Is there a work around to have my Month in all caps?

Comment: This way I see no chance as the format depends on the localization you use. Therefore you will need to convert the date to text and transform it to uppercase (see answer @CLR). But be aware that you cannot calculate with a date converted into text!

Comment: I appreciate your time. I decided to just go with the " ' " answer. I don't love the solution, but it looks like it I'm just a little restricted with getting exactly what I want. Thank you.